# How to manage parallel release branch

Tags: git, version-control

> I'm not a native English user. Please excuse my grammar error.

**Preface:**

Our project is loosely following git-flow structure. Recently, I have to create multiple demo versions which contain one or more demo features each. These features will not necessary be used by the main production version.

Mainly because our sales can use those demo version with more fancy features to explore potential customers.

**Question:**

The question is how do I manage these demo versions and try to fit in the git-flow structure currently using, and can do following things:

1. Supporting multiple separated demo versions at the same time.
2. Capability to merge feature back to develop branch.
3. Capability to update from develop branch. To get any new "main feature" and hotfixes.

**Tempoary Solutions:**
Currently, we are using multiple branches, each represents a demo version, to maintain the versions. However, repeatedly merge from and to develop branch makes things become almost a chaos right now.

I've tried to fork the repo as a demo version. But since almost 90% of code are the same, this solution was not accepted by my colleagues, and it doesn't have the capability to merge with the main repo as well. (Maybe multiple remotes can solve this?)

So, is there any great solutions to apply to this situation?

Comment: Have a look at Tags, perhaps that might be something you could use? There isn't really a one fit solution to branching strategies, what works for one team might be terrible for another team. Can I ask are you guys reviewing the code before it is approved into Develop?

Comment: No. The whole version control system is not so strict in this project. We are using tags to mark out each version we've been created. However, those "demo" version I mentioned in the question section each has its own version code and version name to maintain. Not a single commit.

Or there's more about Tags that I can use in this scenario?

Comment: @TomazWang have you get the answer which help you solve the problem? If yes, please mark it. And it will help others who have similar questions.

Comment: @Marina-MSFT  Yes. In fact, these answers and discussions are all helpful. I will mark the answer that helps me the most. Thanks for the reminding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Branches vs. Repos*

I don't think you can do any better than using branches for demo versions.  The current difficulty, it sounds like, is the interaction between the mainline development and the demo versions.  If you have to make those interactions happen, then having to do them across repo boundaries won't make things any easier. (And of course if you didn't need to do them... you just wouldn't do them and there wouldn't be a problem to begin with.)

The question isn't whether patterns can be developed that would allow you to migrate changes between repos as needed; the question is what you would get for that effort, relative to using branches. In other words, given how much flexibility git gives you within a repo, what do you expect to gain by using multiple repos?

Apart from the complexity, what you *lose* by using multiple repos is a single, comprehensive project history that can easily answer questions like "when the Yoyodyne account gave positive feedback on Feature X, what mainline features were they working against? Because we're seeing this weird bug..."

*So how could it be better?*

It sounds like the branch/merge patterns for demo branches may be the real issue. Having clear (and probably minimal) standards around this can go a long way.  What exactly that should look like will be a team-specific decision, but some ideas:

You might want to avoid merging *from* a demo branch.  If a group of features is accepted based on a demo, that's probably the time to go back to the feature branches and run them through the usual integration and testing procedures through develop.  This allows you to promote features independent of the evolution of a particular demo.  It also allows demo developers to determine whether they're making changes to a particular feature (in which case, update the feature branch and re-merge to the demo), or just doing demo-specific work that will never belong to any of the features (without fear that it might end up accidentally merged to main-line develop).

If you need to know what features are in a demo, `git branch --list` has the `--merged` option

```
git branch --list --merged demoXYZ
```

If you don't delete branches as they're merged to `develop`, then excluding those is a little trickier than I'd like; I usually just make a separate list of branches *not* in develop

```
git branch --list --no-merged develop
```

and use something like `comm` to find which of those are in the branch list for the demo.

That leaves merges *to* the demo branch.  To minimize the chaos, you might limit those to "from `develop` only" and only do them when truly necessary.  (Having a demo branch fall behind develop isn't ideal, but if you're following my above advice then the features involved haven't been through mainline integration and testing yet anyway, so it might not be as critical as it seems.)

If a reasonably small team works on a given demo, you could rebase the demo to keep up with `develop` instead of merging (though if many developers work on the demo at once, this may not be the best option since developers would have to recover from upstream rebase after each time).

Comment: Thanks. Merge from the feature branches can be a very helpful solution and using single repo seems to be more acceptable to my colleagues.

One thing I didn't understand. In the last of your suggestion, you mentioned **rebase** the demo branch to develop. It will discard the previous feature on the demo branch, right?

Comment: No, rebase wouldn't discard anything from the demo branch. Generally rebase should have a similar effect to a merge, except with a different (many people say simpler, certainly more linear) commit topology in the history.

Answer (score 0):

Since these demo versions are mainly to attract potential customers, so it’s far away from your production version (they are loose connected). And I recommend you **manage these demo version into different git repositories**. With different git repositories, you can:

**1.Parallel update the demo versions.**

**2.Apply demo version into develop branch:**

```
# in local repo contains develop branch
git remote add demo1 <URL for a demo> -f 
#use gitk --all to find a commit which you want to apply on develop branch
git checkout develop
git cherry-pick <the commit you found>
```

**3.Update demo version from develop branch:**

```
# In a demo repo
git remote add dev <URL for develop repo> -f
# find the commit id you want to update to demo repo by gitk --all
git cherry-pick <the commit you found>
```

Comment: Using separated repo might actually be the simplest way to solve this problem. But I still have to talk my colleagues into this.

Comment: Yeah, the method also need to be accepted by your colleagues since it's team work :)